# How to set device to silent mode without vibration

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

My app has a certain functionality in which I need to set device to silent mode without vibration. This is triggered by the arrival of a notification.

I used the following code to do this:

```
AudioManager audioManager =  (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

This works when the device screen is ON, but does not work many times, when the device screen is OFF (when it is left idle) for some time.

Is there any way to make this work *everytime*, even when the phone screen is OFF?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

this will lead to a pattern of vibrate use the notification Builder and remove the set vibrate, this will disable the vibration.

**Example of handling the sound and vibrate:**

```
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setLights(Color.parseColor("#ffb400"), 50, 10)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500, 500, 500})
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, the thing is, I am not creating the notification, and I have no control over it. I have to enforce the above functionality when I get an incoming notification from some other app.